# Правильное согласование

Tags: согласование

Речь о таком предложении: "90% лекарств из тех, что сейчас продаются (или продается?), - подделки" Как тут лучше согласовать слово "продается"?
Заранее благодарю за помощь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Правильно: "90% лекарств из тех, что сейчас продаются, - подделки". Союзное слово ЧТО заменяет союзное слово КОТОРЫЕ, согласующееся с указательным словом ТЕХ во множественном числе.